# Task management

Tags: task, toit

Few questions about tasks:

1. In all examples (**Tasks in Toit** section) tasks are "created" in the *main* section of app. Does this mean that tasks cannot be created in the *class*? I tried this and got a compilation error:

```
    class Receiver :
      task :: receive
      receive :
        while true :
          sleep --ms=100
          print "inside thread"
    
    ./web.toit:51:8: error: Unexpected token: ::
      task :: receive
           ^~
    ./web.toit:51:3: error: Missing body
      task :: receive
      ^~~~
    Compilation failed.
```

2. As can see from the examples, *lifecycle* tasks coincides with the *lifecycle* of the application itself. In any case, until I found an opportunity to *create* a task, *run* it, apply *pause/suspend/freeze*, *resume*, *cancel/delete* task & etc. to the task. Do these opportunities exist or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create tasks inside a class, but you would need to do it in inside a method or as part of a field-initializer. But be aware that field-initializers can't access `this`, and thus no method of `this`.

Let's say you want a field in your receiver-class that contains the task. Then you would want to write:

```
class Receiver:
  task_ := null

  constructor:
    task_ = task:: receive

  receive:
    while true:
      sleep --ms=100
      print "inside thread"
```

You can cancel a task by calling `cancel` on it. As soon as it hits a yield point it will stop.

There is currently no way to pause/resume a task from the outside. Given your feedback we are discussing the possibility of adding this feature to it, though.

For now you would probably just use synchronization primitive like a semaphore for it. You could add it to the beginning of the loop.